# How can I do this? change checkbox from readonly to available for checking

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checkboxlist

I created a list of 5 checkbox using HTML and CSS. The first one is always able to be checked but the other four are initianlly readonly. Then, when the first is checked, the second should change from readonly to be available for checking. Once the second is checked, the third must change as well, and so on. How could I do this?

Comment: This should definitely be done using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** 
Javascript

**more explanation:**

What you want is to `listen` to the first checkbox so you can change a property on the next checkbox.

```
const box1 = document.querySelector('#box1')
const box2 = document.querySelector('#box2')
box1.addEventListener('change', () => {
  box2.readonly = false 
})
```

I didn't test this code but this should get you started

Comment: Thanks I'll check it!!

Answer (score 0):

this code works for more or less common case

```js
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        const item = document.querySelector('#cbk' + i);
        item.addEventListener('change', () => {
            var newId = +item.id.replace('cbk', '') + 1;
            document.querySelector('#cbk' + newId).readonly = false;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check it!!